# method to maintain common sections in .html templates (e.g. header, footer, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, templates

Is there a method available to make maintaining the common sections in `html` templates (e.g. header and footer) easier?

I am trying to explore a `javascript` multi-page app.

In `PHP`, my approach for better code maintenance is to use `require_once(path/to/header)` and simply adjust the code in path/to/header, no need to update all pages that use the header.

Is there a similar method for that to maintain html templates? I know this can be achieved in javascript, but I was thinking of a non-dynamic method for this, for search crawlability sake. Although I have read that google can crawl javascript apps, I decided not to make the app 100% javascript generated, I want to maintain the few common sections as static html.

Anyway, what is a common approach for this scenario? Is there a compiler or something? Because right now I am thinking to build the pages in PHP and then just get the html ouput when I move the code out of development.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search: javascript html template engines:

https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/

Eg.

- pug
- ejs
- Handlebars

Comment: I think handlebars is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!